# UIImagePickerController crashed with "[UIViewController _setCameraOverlayView:]: unrecognized selector" on iOS 11

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ios11

I'm trying to create a customized `UIImagePickerController` with the following code.
**ECPhotoPickerController.h**

```
@interface ECPhotoPickerController : UIImagePickerController
@property (strong, nonatomic) void(^didFinishSavingPhoto)(NSURL* url, UIImage* image);
@property (strong, nonatomic) void(^didDismissed)(void);
@end
```

**ECPhotoPickerController.m**

```
...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
    self.showsCameraControls = false;

    [self setCameraOverlayView:self.overlayView];
    self.delegate = self;        
}
...
```

The customized image picker controller will be presented after I tapped a button, which would invoke the following method.

```
- (void)showImagePicker {

    ECPhotoPickerController* vc = [[ECPhotoPickerController alloc] init];
    vc.didFinishSavingPhoto = ^(NSURL *url, UIImage *image) {
        self.selectedImage = image;
    };
    vc.didDismissed = ^{
        // dismissed
    };
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:true completion:nil];
}
```

But the app will **only** crash on iOS 11 with the log

```
[UIViewController _setCameraOverlayView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x108403dd0
```

and there is anther weird log before the crash.

```
[] <<<< AVOutputDeviceDiscoverySession (FigRouteDiscoverer) >>>> -[AVFigRouteDiscovererOutputDeviceDiscoverySessionImpl outputDeviceDiscoverySessionDidChangeDiscoveryMode:]: Setting device discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None (client: ECalligraphy)
```

The customized image picker class obviously inherit from `UIImagePickerController`.
And when I initialized it with `[[ECPhotoPickerController alloc] init]`, it should invoke the super class's initialization since I didn't implement the initialization of `ECPhotoPickerController`.

I'm really confused about this crash. 
Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I final found the reason!
**The `sourceType` should be specified before the view controller start to be
load on iOS 11.**

That means, you should set the value of `sourceType` during the initialization of your customized view controller or do it for the instance before load.

```
- (instancetype)init { // `initFromNibName` etc. depends on the way you initialize it.
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
        self.showsCameraControls = false;
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Or

```
- (void)showImagePicker {
    ECPhotoPickerController* vc = [[ECPhotoPickerController alloc] init];
    vc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:true completion:nil];
}
```